# JavaScript - Add function to prototype using array notatio

Tags: javascript, arrays, prototype, notation, function-prototypes

Is it possible to do something like that?

```
Foo.add_function = function (callback_name, callback_function) {
    this.prototype[callback_name] = callback_function;
}
```

I need to add a function to prototype in array notation. Thank you.

Comment: @thom So you want to be able to do this: `Foo.add_function('blah', function() { ... });` instead of this: `Foo.prototype['blah'] = function() { ... };`?

Comment: Yes, but this.prototype returns undefined

Comment: Why does this must be a function? Thank you SLaks.

Comment: @thom Because adding methods to `Foo.prototype` only makes sense if you're going to use those methods later. You create instances of `Foo` like so: `var foo1 = new Foo();` and then call the prototype methods on those instances: `foo1.blah()`. If `Foo` is not a function, you cannot make instances of it, so having a `prototype` object is pointless.

Comment: @thom: `prototype` is a property of a function.  Things that aren't functions do not have a `prototype` property.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.
A `prototype` is a normal object; that will work fine.

Note that this will only work if `this` is a function; otherwise, `prototype` won't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, yes:

http://jsfiddle.net/QUFXU/6/

jsfiddle is great, you should check it out when you want to test out simple stuff like this.